# Microsoft Synchronization Services for ADO.NET - Data Synchronzation SentAnchor Issue

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

We are having the following problem using this sql express provider with sql server change tracking…

1. Inserting a new row in Server
2. Synchronizing between server and client
3. Inserted row is added to client
4. Updating the same row in the client
5. Synching back to the server
6. Client updated records are coming part of the incremental inserts instead of incremental updates
7. Due to this Update is not reflected in the server, instead we are getting a conflict message of duplicate row inserting.

Answer (score 0):

am assuming you downloaded a custom sql express provider somewhere as there's no equivalent sql express client sync provider when using sql server change tracking...

have a look at you getincrementalinserts and getincrementalupdates to check why updates are being picked up as inserts.

may i ask why are you using an unsupported provider instead of using the built-in sqlsyncprovider? are you tied up to SQL change tracking?